# Ansible, how to chain regex_replace statements?

Tags: ansible

I have a date that comes in like this `2023-05-10T21:12:42+00:00`.
To get rid of the +00:00 I do this:

```
vars:
    date1: " {{ item.expires | regex_replace('\\+00:00') }}"
```

However, when I print **date1** it prints out `"DATE1::: 2023-05-10T21:05:26"` with a space before 2023.
I then have to do another regex_replace on the **date1** variable to get rid of the space in the beginning and assign it to a new variable like this:

```
date2: "{{ date1 | regex_replace(' ') }}"
```

I wanted to chain the regex_replace together like this but it didn't work:

```
date1: " {{ item.expires | regex_replace('\\+00:00') | regex_replace(' ') }}"
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Unlike 42, a regex is not the answer to everything. If you are going to replace a static part of a string, why don't you use a simple `date1: "{{ item.expires | replace('+00:00', '') }}"`?

Comment: And even if the timezone change, you could `date1: "{{ item.expires.split('+')[0] }}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting extra space because of extra space after the starting double quotes, double quotes preserve the starting space with it.

```
 date1: " {{ item.expires | regex_replace('\\+00:00') }}"
         ^
         ^
         ^
```

Change this to the following and you will get rid of starting space :

```
 date1: "{{ item.expires | regex_replace('\\+00:00') }}"
```